# Threading with parameters of type string

Tags: c#, multithreading, parameters, casting, delegates

Using ParameterizedThreadStart would almost work but it requires object as parameter, which feels very wrong. Is it possible to pass a String through ParameterizedThreadStart?

```
        public void OpenUDirectory(String Directory)
        {
              Items.Clear();
              foreach (FileInfo FI in new DirectoryInfo(Directory).GetFiles())
              {
                    Items.Add(FI.Name);
              }
        }
```

I came up with the idea of adding an extension constructor to ParameterizedThreadStart so that I could cast String to Object and call the base method, but is there a cleaner way?

I'm sure I need to call the Invoke method so I have a delegate:

```
    public delegate void OpenDD(String Directory);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to box is as an `object` when you start the thread. Then cast it back to a `string` and call your method.

That is the way it works since it gives the greatest range of flexibility.

Comment: Alright, if I must do it this way then so be it! Thanks for your help. I do understand this way being the most flexible, object is universal. Thanks.